# websocket_connect how to pass configured AsyncHTTPClient so could specify proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

Using tornado==4.5.3 python==3.5.2

Seems like it could be done via 

`AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")`

but where?

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def open(self, proxy=None):
    proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_username, proxy_password = parse_proxy_dict(proxy)
    connection_request = HTTPRequest(
        url=self.URL, proxy_host=proxy_host, proxy_port=proxy_port,
        proxy_username=proxy_username, proxy_password=proxy_password)
    try:
        self.connection = yield websocket_connect(connection_request)
        self.on_open()
        while True:
            msg = yield self.connection.read_message()
            if msg is None:
                self.on_close()
                break
            yield self.on_message(msg)
    except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit) as error:
        self.on_error(error)
```

> ws on_error: proxy_host not supported

Comment: Put the configuration code before you create the `HTTPRequest`. Or better, yet configure it inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`websocket_connect` only uses parts of the `AsyncHTTPClient` implementation, so it is not affected by `AsyncHTTPClient.configure`. In particular, it cannot use curl, only `tornado.simple_httpclient`, which does not support proxies.